# java thread - how to have a thread that runs each second, and prefferably, in that thread have it do 1 action each 5 seconds?

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a thread that runs each second with the sleep command. this works fine, but I'd like to have it do certain actions every 5 seconds too. Both things should run at the same time.. I've had problems starting a second thread in a first one...

any help please?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html.